# Hash, Objeto ou Dicionário?

Tags: terminologia, objetos, hash, dicionário

Venho estudando python e ruby e vi que diversas outras linguagens assim como essas duas fazem uso de diferentes terminologias para determinar um ' objeto ' Json.

`var objeto =  { 'name' : 'Darth Vader' }`.

A questão é que já vi chamarem em ruby de `hash`***(O que me lembra criptográfia )***, javascript de `objeto` e python de `dicionário`.

- A terminologia muda ?
- Porque não abordam uma terminologia universal já que a estrutura é
  praticamente a mesma?

***Obs:*** Dei o exemplo em json, mas entenda também como tipo primitivo de cada linguagem no contexto da pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu não posso responder por que a terminologia não é universal (será que alguém pode?). Mas eu posso tentar explicar de onde vem cada termo utilizado. Eu não tenho um termo preferido para essa estrutura de dados, e varia dependendo de qual linguagem eu estou usando, mas vou chamá-la aqui de "dicionário".

Em JavaScript (vou usar JavaScript na resposta porque JSON significa "JavaScript Object Notation"), se chama objeto porque os projetistas da linguagem queriam implementar um tipo de orientação a objetos, e o jeito mais simples de fazer isso em uma linguagem dinâmica como JavaScript é usando um dicionário, que relaciona o nome dos membros do objeto (suas funções e atributos) aos seus valores. Os objetos em JavaScript são restritos a usarem strings ou números como chave, mas podem ter qualquer coisa como valor. A propósito, os termos "chave" e "valor" são universais, não importa a linguagem.

Python, outra linguagem dinâmica, seguiu uma ideia parecida à do JavaScript para implementar orientação a objetos: seus objetos usam um dicionário para guardar a relação entre os nomes e os valores de seus atributos, porém fez de uma forma explicita (o que é mais organizado, na minha opinião). Em vez de todo dicionário ser um objeto em Python, existem os dicionários (`dict` e notação `{ 'name' : 'Darth Vader' }`), e qualquer classe dinâmica definida em Python vai conter um membro especial chamado `__dict__`, que é o dicionário que armazena os membros dinâmicos dos objetos daquela classe. Então, eu posso acessar um membro de um objeto de duas maneiras diferentes:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Darth Vader'

dv = Character()
print(dv.name) # Imprime "Darth Vader" na tela
print(dv.__dict__['name']) # Também imprime "Darth Vader" na tela
```

Eu expliquei isso sobre Python para que fique claro o motivo de ser chamado de "objeto" em JavaScript. Mas se JavaScript funde os conceitos de objeto e dicionário em uma coisa só, em Python eles são explicitamente separados, e existem tanto objetos que não dependem de dicionários (pesquise sobre o atributo `__slots__` se estiver interessado) quanto dicionários independente de outros objetos, e pode ser usado explicitamente:

```
>>> d = {'banana': 'amarela'}
>>> d['maçã'] = 'vermelha'
>>> d
{'maçã': 'vermelha', 'banana': 'amarela'}
```

Em Python, a chave não está restrita a strings e números, qualquer objeto *[hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)* pode ser chave. E aí entramos no próximo termo: *hash*. Um objeto *hashable* é aquele que possui definido uma função hash: uma função que recebe o objeto, e retorna um valor inteiro correspondente àquele objeto. Hashes não estão necessariamente atrelados à criptografia, como você falou. MD5, SHA-256, etc. são funções de hash criptográfico. Elas são muito lentas para se usar em dicionários, e são desenhadas para serem difíceis de serem invertidas (dado um valor de hash, é difícil descobrir o valor que gerou aquele hash). Para dicionários, geralmente são usados hashes muito mais simples, que não são necessariamente difíceis de serem invertidos. Envolvem algumas operações bit-a-bit e algumas multiplicações com algum número primo constante e tá pronto. O importante é ser rápido, e o resultado ser bem aleatório, com poucas chances de valores diferentes resultarem em hashes iguais.

Outro nome muito comum para dicionário é "tabela hash". Estritamente falando, tabelas hash são dicionários, mas nem todo dicionário é uma tabela hash, embora tabelas hashes sejam o tipo mais comum de dicionário. Os dicionários do Python, JavaScript e (aparentemente, pelo que você disse) do Ruby são implementados como tabela hash. Esse termo torna explícito o papel da função hash na construção do dicionário.

Um dicionário precisa oferecer um mecanismo rápido para se obter um valor a partir de uma chave, e na tabela hash isso é feito da seguinte maneira: tudo fica armazenado em um vetor de tamanho `M > N`, onde N é número de elementos armazenados. Para armazenar um valor de chave `k`, basta fazer:

```
vetor[hash(k) % M] = valor
```

Lembre-se que `k` pode ser uma string, mas `hash(k)` é um inteiro. A operação `%` (resto de divisão inteira) garante que o valor será entre `0` e `M - 1` (você pode somar 1, se você prefere pensar em vetores indo de `1` a `M`). Quanto maior for `M` e melhor (mais "aleatória") for a função `hash`, menor a chance de duas chaves iguais acabarem na mesma posição do vetor. Mas isso acontece, chama-se "colisão de hash". Quando acontece, mais de um valor é armazenado na mesma posição (geralmente cada elemento do vetor é uma lista ligada que contem todos os elementos com aquele hash). Nesses casos, uma busca pelo elemento de chave `k` requer que essa lista seja percorrida em busca do elemento certo. Por isso se diz que a complexidade média de uma tabela hash seja O(1) (tempo constante, basta poucas operações aritméticas para se encontrar um elemento, no caso médio onde não há colisão), e O(n) no pior caso da improvável situação de todos os elementos da tabela hash caírem na mesma posição do vetor, situação onde a tabela hash se degenera para uma lista ligada.

Outro termo comum para dicionário é "map" (mapa, em português), porque assim como dicionário, passa a ideia de permitir encontrar alguma coisa de forma rápida. Esse termo vem do C++, que tem a estrutura "std::map" (não confunda com `map` de Python e Haskell, que é outra coisa), e ao contrário dos outros dicionários, ela garante que os elementos serão armazenados de forma ordenada, e por isso é geralmente implementada como algum tipo de árvore binária (a implementação mais comum é com uma [árvore rubro-negra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_rubro-negra)), que na prática não é um dicionário tão rápido como uma tabela hash (tem complexidade de O(log n)), mas tem a vantagem de os elementos ficarem ordenados pela chave. Em 2011 foi incluída na linguagem C++ a estrutura "std::unordered_map", que não garante a ordem dos elementos, e portanto portanto pode ser (e é) implementada como uma tabela hash.

Espero ter clarificado a origem de todos esses termos.

Comment: Outro nome usado para a mesma estrutura de dados é "_array_ associativo" ou "tabela (associativa)", que é usado em [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#2.1).

Comment: Maneira legal que encontraram para conseguir orientação a objetos em Javascript. Python por sua vez contém módulos bem elegantes que fariam o que Js fez de forma melhor ( Na minha opinião - com a ideia / implementação de Named Tuple por exemplo ). Deixou muito claro e obrigado pela resposta excelente !